# tkinter : how do I remove all the entries from the treeview and also clear the column names

Tags: python, tkinter

I am able to delete all the content of the tree view using the code

```
tree.delete(*tree.get_children())
```

However the column names remain, and my treeview is pulling different tables so I ideally dont want any column names when rest of the data is deleted. How can I do that?

[image]

```
root = Tk()
root.minsize(width=600, height=700)
#root.resizable(width=0, height=0)

tree = ttk.Treeview(root, selectmode='browse',height='10')
tree.place(x=330, y=45)

vsb = ttk.Scrollbar(root, orient="vertical", command=tree.yview)
vsb.place(x=320, y=45, height=200 + 180)

tree.configure(yscrollcommand=vsb.set)

#frm = Frame(root)
#frm.pack(padx=0, pady=10, anchor='nw')
#frm.pack(side=tk.LEFT,padx=0,pady=10)
#frm.pack(padx=0,pady=10)

tree["columns"] = (1,2)
tree['show'] = 'headings'
tree['height'] = '20'

tree.column(1, width=150, anchor='c')
tree.heading(1, text="Date")
tree.column(2, width=150, anchor='c')
tree.heading(2, text="GT")


def delete_command():
    tree.delete(*tree.get_children())


b2 = Button(root, text="delete all", width=12, command=delete_command)
b2.place(x=130, y=45)

root.title('New Data')
root.geometry('650x500')
#root.resizable(False,False)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change your heading's `text = ""` by getting all the columns from `tree['columns']` and resetting them like so.

```py
def delete_command():
    for col in tree['columns']:
        tree.heading(col, text='')
    tree.delete(*tree.get_children())
```

But in case you also mean to delete all columns then put `tree["columns"] = ()` line in your `delete_command` function to clear all the columns.

Comment: doesn't this have quadratic complexity?